# need simple examples for hasone and hasmany usage

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I have watched the movies and read the documents but I can't understand the usage of hasone and hasmany in agile toolkit!
can anybody give me some simple examples for these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two models with hasOne relation:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
    public $table = 'user';
    function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('name'); 
        $this->addField('email');
        $this->hasOne('role');    // field role_id in database
    }
}    
class Model_Role extends Model_Table {
    public $table = 'role';
    function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('name'); 
    }
}
```

Usage of these two models:

```
$cr = $this->add('CRUD');
$cr->setModel('Model_User',
    array('name','email','role_id'),
    array('name','email','role')
);
```

In Grid you will see field name from role table.
In Form you will see dropdown with all roles in it. You can select one role per user.

Comment: Thank u very much. @vadym could you please give an example for hasmany too?

Comment: actually you just need to add
$this->hasMany('User'); 
in Model_Role. Because every role can be assigned to many users.

Answer (score 1):

Read Agile Toolkit low-level documentation here:

http://agiletoolkit.org/book.pdf

should help you understand models fully.

Comment: roman is this the last version? I have read this book about three or four monthes ago.